# dump cache of bind dns

Tags: dns, cache, bind

when I do rndc dumpdb then this file has no new cache dumped (18.04 was yesterday, I don't know how I did this dump) and looks like:

```
> ; ; Start view _default ; ; ; Cache dump of view '_default' (cache
> _default) ; $DATE 20130418231828 ; ; Address database dump ; ; ; Unassociated entries ; ; ; Bad cache ; ; ; Start view _bind ; ; ;
> Cache dump of view '_bind' (cache _bind) ; $DATE 20130418231828 ; ;
> Address database dump ; ; ; Unassociated entries ; ; ; Bad cache ; ;
> Dump complete
```

Am I right to expect there list of domains beind cached?
when I did: `rndc dumpdb >> dump.txt` empty file has been created.
I see that cache is working because after first search of domain, i.e.

> dig www.boost.org

next lookup for same domain is made immediately, so it is caching. But where is cache stored or more specific, why there is nothing in dump file and only "bad cache" info.

I have compiled bind9 from source, then created dir `var/named` and file there like root_hints, folder `pz`, and named.conf in `/etc/`. Configuration seems working OK since server is started without any errors.

here is info from named.run in var/named, when I tried dump:

> 19-Apr-2013 15:21:48.438 received control channel command 'null'
>   19-Apr-2013 15:21:48.438 received control channel command 'dumpdb'
>   19-Apr-2013 15:21:48.438 dumpdb started
>   19-Apr-2013 15:21:48.491 dumpdb complete

Answer (score 1):

It saves the file in your log location. it doesn't actually output to the screen. mine was saved to /var/log/named/. YMMV.